# Group By in MongoDB using Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I tried to group by data in my table and it worked. but the problem is that the response I receive does not display the structure as I expected.

Transaction.java :
[Transaction.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQipD.png)

[image]

TransactionServiveImpl.java : [TransactionServiceImpl.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJGv.png)

[image]

Response : [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgsSV.png)

[image]

The response I expect is the same as the structure in the model. I think the problem is in the aggregation so that the structure that appears is not what I expected.

can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What is the expected response output (update your post with an example)? And what is the result of the aggregation query?

Comment: Please don't show code as image but prefer copy/paste